# Javascript:history.back is not working in XUL application

Tags: javascript, xul

I have created a XUL application, it has got a link for navigating to previous page. This is my link `<a href="javascript:history.back();">Back</a>`, unfortunately it is not working!!!

In firefox is working as expected, when I run it in XUL it is not working.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no XUL expert, so I don't know why that didn't work, but I think what you're looking for is:

```
browser.goBack();
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xul/browser

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/goBack

Answer (score 1):

Did you look in your error console to see what the problem was? (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>)